# Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Coming from `Windows Phone 8` I have never thought there will be a lot of changes done to the `Windows Phone 8.1` code. Basically I'm just wondering how to do page navigation just like how you would do it on `Windows Phone 8`. To do that you should add:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but that code doesn't work for `Windows Phone 8.1`.

Can someone please help me with this? If possible provide any links or documentation on all the new `Windows Phone 8.1` methods.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: this codes work for me on my nokia 630 with cyan

Comment: Plese refer to [this][1] answer, maybe it could help you... 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28761419/2295643

Comment: NavigationService gives me errors.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, Page Navigation method is like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
```

It means that you will navagate to 'SecondPage', and pass 'param' (a class based on object).

If you needn't to pass any parameters, You can use this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

You can find the documentation [for this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Comment: And If I want to go back, clicking the hardware back button doesn't work so would I have to add the hardware back button pressed event and then enter the page which I want? or is their an easier way?

Comment: You can use NavigationHelper in your SecondPage, so that you don't need to add event handler.For example, you can create a BasicPage instead of BlankPage as your SecondPage. And you will see it.

Comment: wp8.1 is different from wp8.0, but more similar with winrt.

Comment: How To pass multiple Parameters.

Comment: @Devi Prasad You should define a class which contains your multiple parameters.

Comment: This method worked for me in forward navigation.  I added it to the click event in xmal.cs file.

Answer (score 23):

In case you want to go back you can use:

```
if(this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

If you want to go back on the click of back button, you need to override the hardwarebutton event:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if(rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                rootFrame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Make sure to set e.Handled to true.

Comment: ...and don´t forget you can do it at app level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335925/windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-terminates-on-navigating-back-from-second-page

Answer (score 1):

```
// Navigation Without parameters

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));



// Navigation with parameters

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage),MyParameters);
```

Comment: How to pass Multiple Paraeters

Comment: Use array or List<object> , put your parameters in it, and pass the array or the List<object> in the parameter. Do you want a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple parameters:
Its quite late to answer but might help someone. You can create a custom class, set your parameters in it and send its object as a parameter to your target page.

For example. Your custom class:

```
public class CustomDataClass
{
public string name;
public string email;
} 

CustomDataClass myData = new CustomDataClass();
myData.name = "abc";
myData.email = "abc@hotmail.com";

Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), myData);
```

And then on the target page you can retrieve in OnNavigatedTo function like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
CustomDataClass myData2 = e.Parameter as CustomDataClass;
string name = myData2.name;
string email = myData2.email;
}
```

Hope it helps.