# Windows phone 8.1 back button always navigate to main screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have lots of pages in my app . When I click back button it does not navigate to previous page but it navigate to the lock screen where all apps are present . Should I have to write code for back button for navigation??

Comment: Are you targetting Silverlight or WinRT? Are you using NavigationHelper? Have you subscribed to `HardwareButtons.BackPressed`?

Comment: WinRT i am just checking the default behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide sample code

Comment: What sample code? I thought you can provide some :) Please check your app.xaml.cs for eventhandler `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` also check if you hadn't subscribed somewhere to this event elsewhere, especially please check if you have a folder called `Common` and `NavigationHelper.cs` there. If you don't have them, you can add *Basic Page* to your project and this will add some helper files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App terminates on navigating back from second page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335925/windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-terminates-on-navigating-back-from-second-page)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to override `OnBackKeyPress` of the phone to handle where the back button should navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler HardwareButtons.BackPressed, AddressOf HardwareButtons_BackPressed

Private Sub HardwareButtons_BackPressed(sender As Object, e As BackPressedEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
    YourGoBackCode()
End Sub
```

And same in c#

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   YourGoBackCode();
}
```

Comment: I am using c# as language

Comment: VB should be quite easy to understand and convert to c#. I've always thought that every single c# programmer would be way better at programming languages than us who use VB only. Anyways I'll update the answer with c# aswell.