# How to check if OnNavigatedTo was triggered by back button in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Quite a simple question I guess, but I can't seem to figure it out..

I have a MainPage.xaml that runs code on the OnNavigatedTo event. **How can I disable this if the user used the hardware backkey to navigate to this page?**

MainPage => Page2 *USES THE HW BACKKEY* => MainPage.xaml // DO NOT RUN THE CODE

MainPage => Page3 => MainPage.xaml // RUN THE CODE

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!TheUserNavigatedBackFromAnotherPageUsingTheBackkey)
    {
        // RUN FRESH CODE
    }
    else
    {
        // DO NOTHING
    }  
}
```

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the NavigationMode of NavigationEventArgs.

```
if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
{

 // navigation is going backward in the stack

}
```

This means that the navigation is going backward in the stack, but doesn't necessarily mean that the back button was pressed. By calling the Frame.GoBack() method for example, it would still be navigating backward.

Comment: Thanks.. This worked great!

Unfortunately for me the previous MainPage does not hold it's state => all content is gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate back not only with backkey, and you want to check if it was pressed, then hence subscribing to *HardwareButtons.BackPressed* is app-wide, it should be easy to provide a flag, which you can set. Let's create app-wide flag:

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public bool wasBackKeyUsed = false;
     // rest of the code
```

Then you have to check how your backward navigation is performed, there are few ways it can be done:

- if you are using `NavigationHelper` (*Common/NavigationHelper.cs*) then open that file and will see where it subscribes. In the eventhandler of backkey, set the flag just before executing the command:

  ```
  (Application.Current as App).wasBackKeyUsed = true; // set the flag
  this.GoBackCommand.Execute(null); // execute going back
  ```
- if you are handling your backkey yourself and/or in App.xaml.cs via template project ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336005/2681948) may help a little), then set the flag just before `Frame.GoBack();`:

  ```
  (Application.Current as App).wasBackKeyUsed = true; // set the flag
  Frame.GoBack(); // go back
  ```

Once you have your flag, you can use it like this to check whether back key was used for navigation:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //check if BackKeyWas used:
    if((Application.Current as App).wasBackKeyUsed)
    {
        // do some code
        // and remember to restet the flag
        (Application.Current as App).wasBackKeyUsed = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Romasz, I'm wondering how is this an improvement over checking the NavigationMode? It looks to me like a lot of overhead for a simple task. And it's riskier, because you have to remember to reset the flag.

Comment: @igrali Hey, I'm sure in most cases your solution will be sufficient (that's why also voted it up). With standard, template code you are right that my solution unnecessarily complicates the program. With the above code you are just sure that the backkey was pressed. It depends on the rest of the code, how OP is Navigating etc. I'm not only sure how `NavigationMode` and my solution will behave in suspending/resuming - but that's other story. I concur that my solution doesn't have many advantages (if any?), but probably has some educational value ;)