# WP8.1 back button quits the app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

The last time I developed against Windows Phone, it was with version 8. Now I'm making use of 8.1. Maybe this is a new feature from MS, but when I press the back button on the phone, regardless of how deep I'm into the app, the app minimizes. This is seriously annoying! Is there anything that I can do?

Many thanks in advance!
Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App terminates on navigating back from second page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335925/windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-terminates-on-navigating-back-from-second-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal behaviour in Windows Phne 8.1 non-SL apps.
Here a workaround to implement in your `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();   
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;        
}

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```