# Windows Phone device back button would quit the app, but not go to the previous page

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows, windows-10

I am making a Windows 10 Universal App with [this tutorial](http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm). Everything works fine, but on a Windows phone, when a user click on the back button on the device, it would just quit the app. The expected behaviour should be going back to the previous navigated page. How can I handle this for my web app, probably using JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: Do something similar to this, only in JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335925/windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-terminates-on-navigating-back-from-second-page/24336005#24336005

Comment: Thanks! But where should I put the codes?