# App crashes when Navigation from pages via back button

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing Windows Phone 8.1 app with MVVM.

I have base view model class which contains Navigation Service as below:

```
 public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected readonly INavigationService NavigationService;
        //....
    }
```

There is my navigation service class:

```
  public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public void Navigate(Type destinationPage)
        {
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(destinationPage);
        }

        public void Navigate(Type desitnationPage, object parameter)
        {
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(desitnationPage, parameter);
        }

        public void GoBack()
        {
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine when I am binding commands from XAML. There is problem when I want to override `BackButton`. I have also created base page model which also contains `NavigationService`. Each page has an overridde pf `BackPressed` as below:

```
public class BasePage : Page
    {
        protected INavigationService NavigationService => ComponentManager.GetInstance<INavigationService>();

        public BasePage()
        {
            //...
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
       protected virtual void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,    BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            (this.DataContext as BaseViewModel)?.Back.Execute(sender);
        }
}
```

As you see in `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` method I've tried to make it in to ways but none is workings. Every time I press back button application crashes without any error.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335925/windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-terminates-on-navigating-back-from-second-page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the app is crashing, it's just exiting because that is the default behaviour of the back button.

What you need to do is flag that you've handled the back button by adding this line of code in your BackPressed event handler:

```
e.Handled = true;
```