# Windows phone 8.1 navigation

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

In my app, I have 3 pages:

- **MainPage**
- **Page2**
- **Page3**

I want to go back from **Page 3** to **Page2** and to **MainPage** by *Back device button*.
So How should I do it?

Help me, please!

Comment: Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639128.aspx?

Comment: This isn't a give me the codez website. First try something yourself. If you have a specific problem, ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation` in WP 8.1 is totally different from the WP8, where here you only have to use `Frame.Navigate` and then give the `Uri`.

A perfect reference would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation?rq=1).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create an event for the hardware event like this:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

And then handle the event accordingly:

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)        
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));   // page you want to navigate to
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope this helps