# NavigationService class Namespace not found in Windows phone development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Am developing an app for windows phone 8.1, I tried navigating from the MainPage to another page using NavigationService class, But visual studio show no reference for the class(The namespace of NavigationService not found) My Question is how to i locate the NavigationService namespace have tried using System.Windows.Navigation Namespace still not found issue..Am actually new to windows mobile development. or is There other class for Navigating between pages?

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation   (8.1 has a lot of changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its like this. Things have changed in Windows Phone 8.1

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
```