# Windows Phone 8.1 navigate using string instead of a type

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, navigateuri

In Windows Phone 8.1 there is any way to navigate from one page to another using an string instead of a Type?

There is no reflection and Frame.Navigate only accepts type.

Thank you.

Comment: Most people write a NavigationService that wraps the frame navigation an looks up page names in a dictionary. You will still have to register the types somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean, there is no reflection?

Comment: any problem with types?

Comment: @KaiBrummund Nice idea, the best is do a dictionary! :-)

Comment: @BlackCid Having a `NavigationService` ot some sort is generally a good idea, and you should go for it. I'm pretty sure you can also use Reflection, though, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kai Brummund. You should write a NavigationService. A good example of a navigation service is the MVVM light navigation service.  [Here you can find the source code](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(WIN81)/Views/NavigationService.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Or... you just can use [MVVMLight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which comes with an integrated NavigationService (INavigationService).
You set it in ViewModelLocator like this:

```
private const string URL_DETALLE = "/View/DetalleView.xaml";
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    // ...

    var navigationService = this.CreateNavigationService();

    if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<INavigationService>())
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);
    }

    //...
}   

private INavigationService CreateNavigationService()
{
    var navigationService = new NavigationService();
    navigationService.Configure(URL_DETALLE, typeof(DetalleView));

    return navigationService;
}
```

Then in your VM constructor you will recieve this navigaton service and you can use it this way:

```
private INavigationService navigationService;
public DetalleViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    this.navigationService = navigationService;
    this.navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.URL_DETALLE);
}
```

Hope it helps ;)