# How to navigate from one xaml page to another xaml page in visual studio 2013 for windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

```
public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SpillGuard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Error saying Navigation Service doesnt exists in the current context.

Comment: Please use Search button, there were many questions about that - possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Like Romansz said, try searching a little bit harder next time.

`NavigationService` does not exist because it is only used in Windows Phone Silverlight apps.  Use `Frame.Navigate()`:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPage), optionalParameter);
```