# Navigation and Query parameter to another page Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have Windows Phone 8.1 app and I need to navigate from a main page to page "pizdec" with parameteres.

I have a cod which can do it in WP8.0, but how car rewrite it in code WP8.1, I don't know.

Example:

```
private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     if (listbox1.SelectedItem != null)
     {
        var file = listbox1.SelectedItem as StorageFile;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pizdec.xaml?filename=" + file.Name, UriKind.Relative));
        listbox1.SelectedItem = null;
     }
```

I know that I need use `this.Frame.Navigate()` , but I do not understand how to rewrite it to 8.1

Code from `pizdec.xaml`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
      string filename;

    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("filename",out filename))
    {
        DisplayFile(filename);
    }
```

And `NavigationContext`, which no in 8.1

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use following,

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(pizdec), param); //a Windows app syntax. param is parameters you want to pass to pizdec.xaml
```

You can access the paramaters in next page as follows,

```
string filename = e.NavigationParameter as string;
```

Microsoft is trying to make syntax of Windows & windows phone app similar, hence the change. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)